# Getting an Error Inserting Documents into a Mongo collection in C# code

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am requesting data via an API. It returns an array of JSON objects.  I can figure out how to insert the data into the collection

Data from [here](https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all)

The main program

```
static async Task CountriesAsync()
{
    var apiURL = "https://restcountries.com/v3.1/alpha/tto";

    var results = await client.GetStringAsync(apiURL);

    string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
    string databaseName = "world";
    string collectionName = "countries";
    MongoClient dbClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
    var database = dbClient.GetDatabase(databaseName);
    var collection = database.GetCollection<CountryModel>(collectionName);

    BsonArray countryList = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonArray>(results);
    collection.InsertMany(countryList);  **<-- causing an error**
}
```

Model snippet

```
namespace CountryMongoDemo.Models
{
    public class CountryModel
    {
        public Name? name { get; set;}
    }

    public class Name
    {
        public string? common { get; set; }
        public string? official { get; set; }
        public NativeName? nativeName { get; set; }
    }

    public class NativeName
    {
        public Eng? eng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Eng
    {
        public string? official { get; set; }
        public string? common { get; set; }
    }
}
```

JSON data snippet

```
[{ "name" : { "common" : "Trinidad and Tobago", "official" : "Republic of Trinidad and Tobago", "nativeName" : { "eng" : { "official" : "Republic of Trinidad and Tobago", "common" : "Trinidad and Tobago" } } }, "tld" : [".tt"], "cca2" : "TT", "ccn3" : "780", "cca3" : "TTO", "cioc" : "TTO", "independent" : true, "status" : "officially-assigned", "unMember" : true, "altSpellings" : ["TT", "Republic of Trinidad and Tobago"], "region" : "Americas", "subregion" : "Caribbean", , "population" : 1399491, "gini" : { "1992" : 40.299999999999997 }, "fifa" : "TRI", "car" : { "signs" : ["TT"], "side" : "left" }, "timezones" : ["UTC-04:00"], "continents" : ["North America"], "flags" : { "png" : "https://flagcdn.com/w320/tt.png", "svg" : "https://flagcdn.com/tt.svg" }, "coatOfArms" : { "png" : "https://mainfacts.com/media/images/coats_of_arms/tt.png", "svg" : "https://mainfacts.com/media/images/coats_of_arms/tt.svg" }, "startOfWeek" : "monday", "capitalInfo" : { "latlng" : [10.65, -61.520000000000003] } }]
```

Comment: What error / exception did you get?

Comment: I'm getting a Compiler Error CS1503 error on "collection.InsertMany(countryList);"

Error msg: "cannot convert from Mongodb.Bson.BsonArray to System.Collections.Generic.IEnnumerable<CountryMongoDemo.Models.ContryModel>

Comment: Do you just want to insert the name property only to MongoDB collection? If yes, deserialize as `List<CountryModel>`. `List<CountryModel> countryList = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<CountryModel>>(results);` With add `[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]` attribute to `CountryModel`.

Comment: @YongShun
Are you saying that I deserialize it as a List<> and not a BsonArray?

Comment: Yes, as the InsertMany method requires parameters with `IEnumerable<TDocument>`.

Answer (score 0):

*Writing the solution from the comment as the answer post for resolving the question and reading for future readers.*

From the code below:

```cs
public virtual void InsertMany(IEnumerable<TDocument> documents, InsertManyOptions options = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
```

`InsertMany` method only supports the `documents` parameter as `IEnumerable<TDocument>` type.

Hence you should deserialize as `IEnumerable<CountryModel>` instead of `BsonArray`.

```cs
List<CountryModel> countryList = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<CountryModel>>(results);
```

---

While in the JSON response returned from the API provided, there are additional properties that are not covered in your model class and you will get an error due to it. To solve it, you need to apply the `[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]` attribute to the `CountryModel` class to ignore those extra properties.

```cs
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class CountryModel
{
    ...
}
```

> Demo

[image]